# tmux status bar rightmost few chars disappear

Tags: tmux

From time to time I saw my status bar rightmost few chars disappear. For instance, the intended one

```
11:40
```

to be

```
11:4
```

My `.tmux.conf` is as the following:

```
# Set status bar
set -g status-bg black
set -g status-fg white
set -g status-left '#[fg=green]#S'
set -g status-right '#[fg=yellow]#(uptime | egrep -o "[0-9]+ users?, +load.*"|perl -pe "s| averages?||"), %H:%M'
set -g status-left-length 20
set -g status-right-length 40
```

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: try to increase the `status-right-length`

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in your `tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g status-right " #[fg=brightwhite,bg=#363636] %a, %d %b %H:%M #[fg=brightwhite,bg=brightblack] #(whoami)@#h "
```